# How to search auto-generated topic channels by API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want to search an auto-generated topic-channel by API, but I don't know which API to use.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: There's this API endpoint that you should use: [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Comment: I only got user`s channels by the Search.list api, so there is some params should I set to got the YouTube auto-generated channels？@stvar

Comment: The `Search.list` endpoint is the counterpart of the search functionality of YouTube website. This endpoint has own [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) that match almost all the filter parameter that exist of the website. Make sure that you invoke `Search.list` with parameters that match the filter you've set within the website UI.